# Minimize, Restore, Maximize & Full Screen toggle hotkey

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I'd like to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to toggle from if a window is minimized from **Minimized** → **Restore** → **Maximize** → **Fullscreen**

And I'd like <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to toggle the other way around.

I'm not finding any help on the issue.

Which option in which tool can do with? Dconf editor? Compiz Config? Unity Tweak?

Comment: The way stacking window managers work, it would not be evident to have a hotkey that toggles between minimized and other states. When minimizing a window, it looses focus. The next keystroke will thus act on the next active window. You have no way to send for example Alt+up to a (which?) minimized window, unless you do scripting to do this with a well defined window (e.g. a terminal).